# Got error command not found when using command feature:install or features:install in ServiceMix 6.1.0

Tags: command-line-interface, apache-servicemix

After I download Apache ServiceMix 6.1.0 and unzip it. Then start up service mix. Then I type command feature:install or features:install. I keep got error command not found. Do features:* or feature:* command was remove from servicemix 6.1.0. What command was replace for these features:* or feature:*? If we want to used these command features:* or feature:*, how could to add it to service mix 6.1.0.

Comment: I just downloaded ServiceMix 6.1.0 and tried `feature:` commands ; working fine. But there is no such command as feature**s**. Just to be sure, can you try writing _feat_ in the console and then hiting _<tab>_ ?

Comment: Yea the official documentation is wrong... it says features:<something> on multiple occasions...

Answer (score 0):

Some commands have changed between Karaf 2 and Karaf 3, here is the list of the new commands:

http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-3.0.x/update-notes.html

Check which version of Karaf your servicemix use, the to have a full description you can check the full documentation of the **Karaf Runtime** documentation here:

http://karaf.apache.org/documentation.html